# How to skew values due to a fixed pivot and a moving point?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, svg, skew

Let say I've a list of points, which got its own value:

```
point index 0 = 0
point index 1 = 50
point index 2 = 50
point index 3 = 60
point index 4 = 80
```

Graphically, somethings like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4et0wf61/) (considering the values in pixels):

[image]

Now, suppose I need to skew each point according to the "raising" of the first point, keeping the last point fixed. i.e. move "up" the point at index 0 to `0` and keep the last point at `80`:

```
point index 0 = 0
point index 4 = 80
```

Mentally, I see the points in the middle skewing/stretching accordly. Such as take the lines and stretch/rotate towards 0. I need the list of the new values for the points in the middle, keeping the X-value for each points.

How would you apply mathematically this transformations? Which should be the formula? Linear interpolation? Can't catch the algo...

Probably with build-in methods as rotate and translate in `SVG` (and other systems) this will be achievable easily, but I'd like to know the math, so I can apply this in context where there isn't build-in methods.

i.e. `SVG` and/or `Javascript` here should just be tools for apply the math.

Comment: Isn't this just a linear scaling of the path around the endpoint? Unless you want a non-uniform effect e.g. exponentially decaying displacement?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: it could be. Not sure how I would apply a linear scaling considering a moving point (the first) and a fixed one (the last). Can you give to me an example? For example: The two middle values at 50 won't get the same value applied. One would be more "high" then the other (because the path become more inclined after the transformation). Not sure if you got what I mean :)

Comment: I don't understand why you regard the "moving" aspect as a problem - why can't a scaling simply be re-applied every time the point is moved?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: no its not a problem, at all :) Yes, I can apply the re-scaling every time I move it. Can you give to me an example on how you would scale the points in the middle keeping the last fixed and changing the first at 0? ps: x-values for each points shouldn't change.

Comment: Assume i) the fixed endpoint is `(ex, ey)`, ii) the moving endpoint starts at `(mx, my)` and moves to `(mx, mY)`, iii) an arbitrary point on the path starts at `(px, py)`. The scaled new Y-coordinate is given by `pY = py + (mY - my) * (px - ex) / (mx - ex)`.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: it seems wonderful. How its called this formula?

Comment: I don't know, it's just simple math. It's similar to linear interpolation I guess.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: thanks dude, it works like a charm :*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scale and skew are different algorithms. Point in case: if your point `index 0` moves from 50 to 0, should point `index 1` also move from 50 to 0, or to 9?

[image]

First, let's rewrite you points. Each of them has two coordinates, after all:

```
index 0: (0, 50) // I suppose 0 for the y value was a typo on your part
index 1: (90, 50)
index 2: (140, 50)
index 3: (210, 60)
index 4: (500, 80)
```

The `scale` transform function stretches away from vertical part of the fixed point:

```
( x, y ) => ( x, y * factor  + shift )
            factor = (fixedY - movingYNew) / (fixedY - movingYOld)
            shift = fixedY * (1 - factor)
```

With `fixedY = 80, movingYOld = 50, movingYNew = 0` that gives you `factor = 8/3, shift = -400/3` and the following transformed points:

```
index 0: (0, 50) => (0, 0)
index 1: (90, 50) => (0, 0)
index 2: (140, 50) => (0, 0)
index 3: (210, 60) => (0, 26.777)
index 4: (500, 80) => (0, 80)
```

The `skew` transform function stretches in the vertical direction, but dependent on the horizontal distance to the fixed point

```
( x, y ) => ( x, x * skewFactor + y + shift )
            factor = (movingYOld - movingYNew) / (fixedX - movingX)
            shift = movingYNew - movingYOld
```

With `fixedY = 80, movingYOld = 50, movingYNew = 0` that gives you factor =  1/10, shift = -50` and the following transformed points:

```
index 0: (0, 50) => (0, 0)
index 1: (90, 50) => (0, 9)
index 2: (140, 50) => (0, 14)
index 3: (210, 60) => (0, 31)
index 4: (500, 80) => (0, 80)
```

Comment: Its pretty much what @meowgoesthedog suggested to me as "linear interpolation". Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jr5a2snu/ The result are the same (have if it seems your formula its different). So `skew` is a linear interpolation?

Comment: The scale function is mathematically equivalent to his. - There are `skewX()` and `skewY()` transform functions in SVG and [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skewX); the mathematical term is [shear mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping).

Comment: nope. His formula gives to me your "skew" results, not the scale ones.

Comment: Oops, I see. I was duped be his earlier comments about "skaling".

Comment: Apologies for my casual use of terminology - I wasn't aware of the distinction between the two transformations.